# Remove print dialogue when printing with gython Ghostscript

Tags: python, ghostscript

Currently I have the following code.

My issue is a small loading window opens while printing and its very easy to click cancel.

Any one know how to print silently (i.e no windows at all)?

I've tried a myriad of options and none seem to work.

```
def print_pdf(pdf):
    
    args = [
            "-dPrinted", "-dBATCH", "-dNOSAFER", "-dNOPAUSE", "-dNOPROMPT"
            "-q",
            "-dNumCopies#1",
            "-sDEVICE#mswinpr2",
            f'-sOutputFile#"%printer%{win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()}"',
            f'{pdf}'
        ]   
    
    ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
```

Alternatively does anyone know of another way to print PDF's to printer?

Answer (score 0):

> The mswinpr2 device supports a limited number of command-line parameters (e.g. it does not support setting the printer resolution).

It may seen counter intuitive but try [-dNoCancel](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Devices.html#supported-command-line-parameters) (case sensitive) means don't show the Progress Box with Cancel button. However beware with the -q you will then need to watch the printer icon on the tool bar.

> `-dNoCancel`
> Hides the progress dialog, which shows the percent of the document page already processed and also provides a cancel button. This option is useful if GS is intended to print pages in the background, without any user intervention.

```
def print_pdf(pdf):
    
    args = [
            "-dPrinted", "-dBATCH", "-dNOSAFER", "-dNOPAUSE", "-dNOPROMPT"
            "-q -dNoCancel",
            "-dNumCopies#1",
            "-sDEVICE#mswinpr2",
            f'-sOutputFile#"%printer%{win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()}"',
            f'{pdf}'
        ]   
    
    ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
```